How to extend Google login (OAuth2) with custom user-info parameters on the screen?
I do not know how to solve my problem: the token has custom attributes (fields) that Google itself provides - mail, name, and so on. But this data is not enough, and I want to get from the user other fields from the interface form (phone number, address and so on. d.).
That is: for example, when logging in, the user enters their residential address.
The question is, is there any way to get such additional parameters during the authorization process via oauth2?
I was looking at OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver, but I can't get the data embedded in the URL.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
